# Calling a RESTful Web services for Data (Oauth 2.0 password Grant Type)

Tags: arcgis

Good Day,
Is it possible to GET data into a content set for ArcGIS online? I am new to ArcGIS online. Was wondering how I can call (GET) an endpoint in json format (with some lat and lon) to dynamically update the data set when a new object is entered.

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use GET to query a Feature Service: [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/query-feature-service-layer-.htm) ([example](https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA/MapServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&having=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&historicMoment=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&queryByDistance=&returnExtentOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&quantizationParameters=&featureEncoding=esriDefault&f=pjson)). To edit or add data, you'll want to use ApplyEdits - that is POST only, as you can see in [the documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/apply-edits-feature-service-layer-.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using Rest API and many other Languages.
Here are the list of all the tutorials with different languages.
Its very helpful and well guided.

All the tutorials with Rest API : https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/?product=rest-api&topic=any

Add/Update/Remove feature with Rest API and Json formats : https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/rest/add-edit-and-remove-features/